# how to remove the style tags from the header section

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, minify, meta-tags

I am using angular js and deployed a site, In the head part of my website there are a lot of style tags are coming in the console like the below image, I attached a snap of my website console. I don't know where those tags are coming from and how can I remove those style tags from the head of the website

[image]

Comment: Can you please share your code, so we can debug it's hard to understand from an image how the style tags are getting generated. Please provide [Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) not just the image.

Comment: You can try the solution provided in my answer. I hope it will work as per your expectation.

Answer (score 5):

As of my understanding, you are using [Angular Material Design](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) and it is responsible for adding the `style` tags in your `head` section. It all happens under the hood, you can follow [this link](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/05_under_the_hood) to know more. I think you no need to worry about removing this style tags and all because it came as functionality. [Angular Material Design](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/) dynamically inject this `style` tags for theming purpose.

Reference: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/05_under_the_hood

Thank you.

**EDIT**

If you don't want to generate themes by default then you can use

`$mdThemingProvider.generateThemesOnDemand(true);`

*Example*:

```
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
    .config(function($mdThemingProvider, $provide) {
      //disable theme generation
      $mdThemingProvider.generateThemesOnDemand(true);
      $provide.value('themeProvider', $mdThemingProvider);

    })
    .run(['themeProvider', '$mdTheming', function(themeProvider, $mdTheming) {
      //create new theme
      themeProvider.theme('default')
      .primaryPalette('pink')
      .accentPalette('orange')
      .backgroundPalette('yellow');

      //reload the theme
      $mdTheming.generateTheme('default');

      //optional - set the default to this new theme
      themeProvider.setDefaultTheme('default');
    }]);
```

Reference: https://material.angularjs.org/latest/Theming/04_multiple_themes

Comment: i have seen some of the sites which are using angular material in their `head` section there were no style tags like my site, i want to hide those from my `head` section @Arpit Meena

Comment: when we use the above code as like you mentioned, my total site theme changed all the color changed @Arpit Meena

Comment: @Midhunsai, Do you need multiple themes? or you want a single theme for your website?

Comment: single theme ie., default material them @Arpit Meena

Comment: @Midhunsai I have updated the answer please check and let me know it works for you or not.

Comment: it's showing an error `unknown provider $mdTheming` in the console, i tried like this `angular.module('core').config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$mdTheming', '$mdThemingProvider',
  function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$mdTheming, $mdThemingProvider) { 
  $mdThemingProvider.generateThemesOnDemand(true); 
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('myDefaultTheme')
    .primaryPalette('purple')
    .accentPalette('green');   
   $mdTheming.generateTheme('default');
   $mdThemingProvider.setDefaultTheme('default');
});` @Arpit Meena

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143270/discussion-between-arpit-meena-and-midhunsai).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to remove all the style tags :

```
var st = document.getElementsByTagName('style');
```

and add a loop to remove all of them.

```
for(i = 0 ; i < st.length ; i++){

    st[i].parentNode.removeChild(st[i]);

}
```

Comment: may i know the reason why those style tags are coming in the header when it is deployed @Bhansa

Comment: You should probably check your code, whether you are generating them check your html file.

Comment: if i coded the inline styling then those style tags will come in header? @Bhansa

Comment: @Midhunsai they already are in the header, but if they are inline they won't for your concern.

Comment: i have placed your code in my header controller, is the right place to put your code  for removing the style tags? @Bhansa

Comment: You should add it below the styles which are loading, or in the end of the body, so that document loads and it can find all those styles.

Comment: still the problem was not resolved those tags are coming @Bhansa

Answer (score 2):

Please Try with below JQuery code

```
$('style[md-theme-style]').remove();
```

Comment: Well, that's one way of "answering the question".. What about the element that style actually affected?

Answer (score 0):

**Reason :**

Angular-material includes some default `theme` css as a constant variable.

You can check [here(angular-material.js)](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.js).

[image]

When we load this library in the browser it adds lots of `style tags` dynamically into the `<HEAD>` section of the Page.

**How to disable ?**

You can override the `constans`.It will result in not adding theme classes on components.

```
angular(myApp, [ ngMaterial, myAppModules ]).constant("$MD_THEME_CSS","");
```

You can also look into the [angular-material.js](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-material/1.1.4/angular-material.js). This solution is also proposed in library itself.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to disable theme generation before and then enable the one you want?

```
angular.module('myApp', ['ngMaterial'])
.config(function($mdThemingProvider) {
  //disable theme generation
  $mdThemingProvider.generateThemesOnDemand(true);

  //themes are still defined in config, but the css is not generated
  $mdThemingProvider.theme('altTheme')
```

.primaryPalette('purple')
    .accentPalette('green');

//generate the predefined theme named altTheme
  $mdTheming.generateTheme('altTheme');
});

Answer (score 0):

When material.js loads into your browser this adds lots of css style tags dynamically to the page document. To disable them you will need to recompile angular-material yourself using the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/angular/material.git
```

Then install dependancies:

```
cd material
npm install
```

Then go to gulp/util.js and change line 53 from:

```
var jsProcess = series(jsBuildStream, themeBuildStream() )
```

to be:

```
var jsProcess = series(jsBuildStream)
```

Then run the build process:

```
gulp build
```

Comment: i am using grunt not gulp @MehulJoshi

Comment: this is not about your build system, you have to go to node module directory, and then have to make changes to material and then you will have to build again, for changes to reflect. for that you will have to install gulp.